# Calling std-based host function from a pallet

Tags: pallet, runtime, no-std, host-functions, runtime-interface

Based on:

- [Use std only rust library to extend substrate runtime interface？](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4903/use-std-only-rust-library-to-extend-substrate-runtime-interface/)
- [How to understand [runtime-interface] and `Externalities`?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/how-to-understand-runtime-interface-and-externalities/)

I understand that I should be able to:

1. have a crate that is **not** wasm/no-std friendly, e.g. relies on `std` library
2. put its functionalities under a trait with `#[sp_runtime_interface::runtime_interface]` attribute
3. register corresponding host function in the node's executor
4. call the functionality from a pallet

However, when I'm trying to do so, I'm getting the classical error:

```
  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `serde` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/ec2-user/remote-builds/8351322047856898080/target/release/wbuild/aleph-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-adc573607c02c939.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/ec2-user/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-10-30-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-013c81c18ec4954a.rlib
```

I'm pretty sure that I have set up all `default-features` and `/std` features correctly. The problem is gone when I remove the std-based dependencies from my crate, but that's the thing - I want to use them in my runtime.

Maybe the problem is in the way I should call the host function from the pallet. I have put my crate as a dependency and I'm calling it with `<crate_name>::<snake_case_trait_name>::<trait_method_name>`. Is this the correct way or should I use some magic with externalities etc. I couldn't find any example in the Substrate repo, apart from `statement_store`, which is actually is no-std/wasm compatible, so it doesn't help.

Comment: @bkchr you have answered with `You just need to call dvm_ext::evm_event(events)`, but I couldn't even find a module with `trait_ext` name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substrate provide [sp-std](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/primitives/std) and [sp-io](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/primitives/io) for `std` calls in a `no_std` environment. By the error I can understand you are using `std` instead of `sp-std` or `sp-io` so it is giving you the error `duplicate lang item in crate`. I hope this helps.

Comment: well, I'm using 3rd party library that uses std things, so there's no way that I can substitute `std` with `sp-std`; is this the case that I can use std-based code in a host function only if it delegates std things to `sp-std`?

Comment: Yes it should work like this

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered the HostFunctions in your host code, you should just include the `sp_your_runtime_interface` in your pallet to call the host function. Including your std-required crate in pallet will cause importing std.